# .NET web service programming with iPhone clients in mind

Tags: .net, iphone, objective-c, web-services

I need to write a .NET web service which will be consumed exclusively by an iPad app.

We are leaning towards using REST but could someone let me know whether this is the easier way (from the iPhone side).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REST/JSON combined with WCF on the .NET side seem to be the way to go with iPhone/iPad apps.

Here is a really good tutorial on how to connect using Json:

http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/

And you can download the iPad client JSON library from here:

http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a web app or is there going to be an iOS native app that needs to access the data? Actually...not sure that matters...either way, as long as you are using standard web technologies to pass the data back and forth, you should be fine...though your particular iOS app developer may have a particular preference.